# Empathy unable to automatically connect at startup

Tags: 11.10, empathy

I have a problem with Empathy being unable to automatically connect at startup. I have noticed that when Empathy is started manually it logs in automatically but Ubuntu still notifies *Password required*.

Is this a problem with the Gnome keyring?

Answer (score 2):

Go in Ubuntu Dash -> Search for "startup programs" and add empathy there with command empathy. Be sure, that you saved your account password in empathy, if you mean that password question.

the *Password required* message is a bug reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/896590
you can vote for this bug (mark that it affects you) if you want to increase the attention it gets by developers.